# WaterMarking on Image in C#?

Tags: c#, math, geometry

I want to put water mark on center of image diagonally.My code doing well but water mark not appear in center of every image.I think there is problem in postioning of watermark text where i hard code values.How can I write generic formula for postioning of watermark text.

```
    private MemoryStream ApplyWaterMark(MemoryStream stream)
        {

            System.Drawing.Image Im = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);                // 
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(Im);

            // Create a solid brush to write the watermark text on the image
            Brush myBrush = new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(25,
            System.Drawing.Color.LightSteelBlue));

            var f = new System.Drawing.Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, 30);
            // Calculate the size of the text
            SizeF sz = g.MeasureString("TEST WATER MARK", f);

            int X, Y;
            X = ((int)(Im.Width - sz.Width) / 2)-1162;
            Y = ((int)(Im.Height + sz.Height) / 2)-127;



            g.RotateTransform(-45f);
            g.DrawString("TEST WATER MARK", f, myBrush,new System.Drawing.Point(X, Y));
            g.RotateTransform(45f);

            Im.Save(OutPutStream, ImageFormat.Png);//save image with dynamic watermark

            return OutPutStream;
        }
```

Comment: Why are you subtracting `1162` and `127`?

Comment: @Oded  he's applying a -45 degree rotation to the image before drawing his watermark.  The hard coded values are a fudge to try to get the text to draw parallel (and centered upon) the diagonal.  He then rotates +45 degrees to get the image back to square.  The fudge is one problem, the arbitrary 45 degree is also another.  The angle should be calculated by arctan(Height/Width) and the position of the text derived similarly.

Comment: actually i set the postion of text according to specific image.so, i put 1162 and 127.But i want some generalize formula.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the watermark diagonally by this way

```
     Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap);
     Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newBitmap);

     // Trigonometry: Tangent = Opposite / Adjacent
     double tangent = (double)newBitmap.Height / 
                      (double)newBitmap.Width;

     // convert arctangent to degrees
     double angle = Math.Atan(tangent) * (180/Math.PI);

     // a^2 = b^2 + c^2 ; a = sqrt(b^2 + c^2)
     double halfHypotenuse =(Math.Sqrt((newBitmap.Height 
                            * newBitmap.Height) +
                            (newBitmap.Width * 
                            newBitmap.Width))) / 2;

     // Horizontally and vertically aligned the string
     // This makes the placement Point the physical 
     // center of the string instead of top-left.
     StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat();
     stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
     stringFormat.LineAlignment=StringAlignment.Center;

     g.RotateTransform((float)angle);            
     g.DrawString(waterMarkText, font, new SolidBrush(color),
                  new Point((int)halfHypotenuse, 0), 
                  stringFormat);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try computing the coordinates (X, Y) this way for center of the image:

```
int X, Y;
X = (int)(Im.Width / 2 - sz.Width / 2);
Y = (int)(Im.Height / 2 - sz.Height / 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Water mark at the bottom with multiple colors

```
public void AddWatermark(string watermarkText, string image, string TColor) 
{       

    System.Drawing.Image bitmap = (System.Drawing.Image)Bitmap.FromFile(Proot + image);
    Font font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

    RectangleF rectf = new RectangleF(70, 90, 90, 50);

    Color color = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0);
    try
    {
        if (TColor.ToUpper() == "RED")
        {
            color = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0);
        }
        else if (TColor.ToUpper() == "WHITE")
        {
            color = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255);
        }
        else if (TColor.ToUpper() == "BLACK")
        {
            color = Color.FromArgb(155, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        else if (TColor.ToUpper() == "GREEN")
        {
            color = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 255, 0);
        }
    }
    catch { }


    //     WHITE (255, 255, 255, 255)
    //     RED   (255, 255, 000, 000)
    //     GREEN (255, 000, 255, 000)
    //     BLUE  (255, 000, 000, 255) 
    //     BLACK (150, 000, 000, 000)
    //     PURPLE(255, 125, 000, 255)
    //     GREY  (255, 128, 128, 128) 
    //     YELLOW(255, 255, 255, 000) 
    //     ORANGE(255, 255, 125, 000)

 //   Point atpoint = new Point(bitmap.Width / 2, bitmap.Height / 2);
    Point atpoint = new Point(bitmap.Width / 2, bitmap.Height - 10);

    SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(color);
    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

    StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

    graphics.DrawString(watermarkText, font, brush, atpoint, sf);
    graphics.Dispose();
    MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
    bitmap.Save(m, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

 //   Response.WriteFile("images/DefaultLogo.png", true);
    m.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);

    m.Dispose();
    base.Dispose();
}
```